# Relation and Entity Share a Field / Reference Each Other

Tags: 7, entities

I can't seem to get this to work. I've searched and search, and maybe I'm not using the correct terminology, but I need to add a custom field to a Relation that reads a value from the Entity its related to. Or another way to put this, I need a field from the Relation to update a field in an Entity when the Relation is updated. Example:

Entity -> Worker
Relation -> Employed At
Entity -> Company

I want to update my custom field "classification" through the Employed At Relation and then see that change reflected in the "classification" custom field in my Worker Entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about the [Relation](http://drupal.org/project/relation) module, then you can use [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) to trigger entity updates whenever a relationship (which is also an entity) changes.

The workflow would be like this :

1. Trigger on entity update.
2. Check that entity is a relation.
3. Update linked entity.

Check the video documentation on [Relation](http://drupal.org/project/relation), there are two ([1](http://vimeo.com/28479420), [2](http://vimeo.com/28178715)) of them talking about Rules.

Comment: When you say "1. Trigger on entity update", do you mean "trigger on Relation update"?

Comment: Yes, bear in mind that a relation is an entity from drupal point of view.

Comment: Thanks, those videos helped get familiar with it all. I can get a the relation type I want, but not sure how to get the linked entity. For Events I have "After Updating a Relation", for Conditions I have "Data Comparison" which I use to select the correct Relation Type. This is good because it gives me access to the fields that I need from that specific Relation. I've tried a few Actions, Fetch Entity by Property or ID, but I'm hitting a wall. I think I might be missing something concerning endpoints?

Comment: What do you mean by endpoints ?

Comment: Endpoints (an array I'm assuming) being the entities on either end of the Relation. Ex: Worker = endpoint[0], Company = endpoint[1]

Comment: This worked, I'm getting a Revision ID error when I try saving the related entity, but I believe this to be a bug that is unrelated to the process, so I'm marking this as solved.